# Meilisearch - what's the differences & relationship among: searchableAttributes, filterableAttributes, faceting

Tags: full-text-search, meilisearch

`searchableAttributes`, `filterableAttributes`, `faceting`.
I've read the documents, but a bit confused.

Please give some insights about:

- Their differences.
- Their relationships.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `searchableAttributes` are attributes where Meilisearch can search in for matching query words.
- `filterableAttributes` are a list of attributes that can be used as filters to refine the search results. Given a movies dataset, if you want to filter movies by `release_date`, you need to first add the attribute `release_date` to the `filterableAttributes` list.

Both `searchableAttributes` and `filterableAttributes` are part of Meilisearch settings. An attribute doesn't necessarily have to be searchable for it to be filterable, so no relation between both.

- `facets` is a search parameter, not a setting, it must be added to a search request. It gives information about the number of documents found per attribute value. If you want to know how many movies there are per genre for a given query, you can pass the `"facets": ["genres"]` as a parameter in the search query like so:

  ```
    curl \
  -X POST 'http://localhost:7700/indexes/movies/search' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{
    "q": "Batman",
    "facets": ["genres"]
  }'
  ```

The response should include a `facetDistribution` object with the information:

```
{
  "hits": [
    …
  ],
  …
  "facetDistribution": {
    "genres": {
      "action": 273,
      "animation": 118,
      "adventure": 132,
      "fantasy": 67,
      "comedy": 475,
      "mystery": 70,
      "thriller": 217
    }
  }
}
```

In order to have the facets information about an attribute, it must be first present in the `filterableAttributes` list.